# $y = xe^{−1/|x|}$ for $−∞ < x < ∞$

Tags: calculus, limits, functions, graphing-functions

(a) Let $f(x) = x − xe^{−1/x}, x > 0$. Show that f(x) is an increasing
function on $(0,∞),$ and $\lim_{x→∞} f(x) = 1$.

(b) Using part (a) and calculus, sketch the graphs of $y = x−1, y = x,
y = x + 1,$ and $y = xe^{−1/|x|}$ for $−∞ < x < ∞$ using the same $X $and $Y$ axes.

My approach: for (a) I could only show $\lim_{x→∞} f(x) = 1$. I proved it using the convergent series expansion of $e^x$.

for (b) the problem lies with $y = xe^{−1/|x|}$. I am not being able to sketch it.

$f'(x)=1-{e^{-1\over x}\over x}-e^{-1\over x}$

Answer (score 0):

For (a), proving that the function is increasing is usually easiest if you prove that its derivative is positive.

For (b), the usual things you must show in a graph are:

- asymptotes (behaviours of the function as $x$ goes to $\infty$ or $-\infty$).
- minimums and maximums
- zeroes (if there are any).

For each of these things, some calculation is required.

Comment: I am not being able to prove that its derivative is positive.

Comment: @Ruddie Did you calculate the derivative? If so, add it to your question.

Answer (score 0):

You already have the derivative:
$$
f^{\prime }(x)=1-\frac{\exp [-\frac{1}{x}]}{x}-\exp [-\frac{1}{x}].
$$
Now write it as
$$
f^{\prime }(x)=1-\frac{1+\frac{1}{x}}{\exp [\frac{1}{x}]}.
$$
Since
$$
\exp [\frac{1}{x}]>1+\frac{1}{x},\;0<x<\infty
$$
$f^{\prime }(x)$ is positive for such $x$. For $x=0$, $f^{\prime }(x)=1$,
whereas for $x\rightarrow \infty, $ $f^{\prime }(x)\rightarrow 0$.